# PDO: Set a custom key to each item in FETCH_ASSOCC result

Tags: php, pdo

I'm fetching a few columns from a table and returning it as json, I want to add a key to the associative array before sending it back to the client.

I'm doing this in the get function:

```
$stmt = $app->pdo->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM item_rnw");
$stmt->execute();

$rnws = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($rnws as $rnw) {
    $rnw["icon"] = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=•|000000";
}

echo json_encode($rnws);
```

Yet logging the response on the client only shows the col1, col2, col3 key + value pairs, no icon key + value.

New to PDO, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also do this, saves the looping:

```
$icon = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=•|000000";
$stmt = $app->pdo->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3, '$icon' as icon FROM item_rnw");
```

Comment: This is a really clean approach but I'd still parameter bind the value, ie `SELECT col1, col2, col3, ? AS icon...`

Comment: Nice answer. Cheers! I am going to use this rather than the loop, didn't realize I could do that. But I will have to accept Phil's answer due to it answering the question :P. Note to self remember bindParam haha! Cheers guys

Comment: @Lee2808 You can give AbraCadaver an up Vote at least, if you want :D

Comment: @Lee2808 You should accept the answer that works best for you. I like this one better

Comment: Yeah you're right, thought I implied in the Q how to do it in the loop. Bed time lol. Cheers again.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're not operating on the items in the array. Try this instead...

```
foreach($rnsw as &$rnw)
```